# select depending on a value from another select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have two md-select as following :

```
<div layout=column>
    <md-input-container flex><label for=organizations>Organization</label>
            <md-select ng-model="dg.selectedOrganization" name=organizations aria-label="Organizations" required>
                    <md-option ng-value=organization ng-repeat="organization in dg.organizations"> {{organization.title}} </md-option>
            </md-select>
            <div ng-messages=dg.myForm.organizations.$error>
                    <div ng-messages-include=messages/messages.html></div>
            </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container flex><label for=rules>Role</label>
            <md-select ng-model="dg.selectedRule" name=rules aria-label="Rules" required>
                    <md-option ng-value=rule ng-repeat="rule in dg.selectedOrganization.rules"> {{rule.title}} </md-option>
            </md-select>
            <div ng-messages=dg.myForm.rules.$error>
                    <div ng-messages-include=messages/messages.html></div>
            </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

So when I select a value from the first md-select (organization), `dg.selectedOrganization` will get the selected value and the second md-select will be populated depending on the selected value. And then when I select something in the second md-select (rules) `dg.selectedRule` will get the selected value.

The problem I had is when I change `dg.selectedOrganization`, the `dg.selectedRule` will always have the old value until I select a new one, normally the `dg.selectedRule` should be null before I select any value after changing `dg.selectedOrganization`.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an onChange handler for the dg.selectedOrganization select

When the onChange event fires, update dg.selectedOrganization.rules and also set dg.selectedRule to a value that exists in dg.selectedOrganization.rules. If you want to set it to an empty value then you will need to ensure that there is an empty value in the select, or you could just set it to the first available option.